# What was that online radio website again Majestic Jukebox Radio streams to?

Tags: radio

Last summer, I found a great radio website which I enjoyed listening to for a few weeks. It featured [Majestic Jukebox Radio](https://www.majesticjukeboxradio.com/). Today, I wanted to visit it agin but I forgot its name and address. Can you help me?

Here's what I remember about it:

- It's a platform hosting hundreds of private radio stations (many in the UK).
- The website's design is red and white and I think its name starts with a B (not sure) and is of medium length.
- You can select a genre on the website and see about a dozen stations each time including their current listeners count (mostly below 20). When selecting one, you can see a map with the station's location.
- I had found the website when looking for blues, rock 'n' roll and rhythm and blues from the 70s and 80s.

I know the information I recall isn't quite specific but maybe someone has already visited the website I refer to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than add "(solved)" to the question title, you can [accept](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found the website again! It's [internet-radio.com](https://www.internet-radio.com/station/majesticjukebox/)

Comment: Oh, for some reason I am not allowed to accept my own answer. Well, consider it hereby solved.

Comment: You have to wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer (just in case someone comes up with an even better answer).

Comment: The "b" that you remembered is maybe because it seems to have the website https://breakcore.org/

Comment: Hi, you can now accept your answer.

Comment: @Angst Yes, that looks quite familiar. Thanks!